# Blueprint & room rental management

Tags: database, sharepoint, blueprint

I work at a university building. We have various professors using various rooms at different times of the year. Who uses which room changes around once or twice a semester. I need a better way to manage who uses the rooms here at the university. We basically have a pdf of the floor plan for the two floors and on there we have written on the sides of the blueprint who is in which room. We need a more presentable method, and hopefully something that has an easy way to look up who is where, and a nice presentable format. Any ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming...

Comment: I know and I'm sorry if I broke any rules, but I figured maybe some programmer here might know of a nice way to do this.

Comment: Even if this was a programming question, it's far too open-ended and opinion baiting.

Comment: My apologies. I just need some advice. Was thinking visio but someone mentioned a program named glyffy below. Looking into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-sketch the floor plan as [glyffy](https://www.gliffy.com)  diagram and publish it to your intranet site or public Web site.